# How to check if an uploaded N x M csv file has certain headers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file-upload

How would I check a CSV with unknown amount of rows and columns whether it has some certain headers?

Let's say I have a CSV file called Testy.py and it has M columns with M headers. But I can only validify this CSV file if it has the headers: ID in the first column and Name in the second column. Meaning if the file does not fulfill the requirements, I will set the uploaded file to 0. I have the following code, and I tried to use the if statement under the Cols definition but it doesn't work.

```
#Loading a file
filename = input("Please enter .csv filename: ")
path = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

#*If the file is in the path, the code will run*
if filename in path[:len(path)]:   
        print("\nData has been loaded!\n")
        loadcsv = pd.read_csv(filename, header = None, names = cols)
        cols = ['StudentID', 'Name']
        if (loadcsv.iloc[0] != cols).all():
            print("The uploaded file is not valid")
        break
else:
        print("\nFile has not been found.") 
        #File upload gets reset if not found in listdir. 
        loadcsv = np.array([])
```

Comment: why not change parameter `header='infer'` in `read_csv()` ?

Comment: Well the problem is that I started programming 2 weeks ago so I don't have a clear overview of what I'm doing... So I'm trying to see an example of a code that may help me here. :-)

Comment: check my answer. I think it should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will read csv and check the columnnames are right or not.

```
            filename = input("Please enter .csv filename: ")
            path = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

            #*If the file is in the path, the code will run*
            if filename in path[:len(path)]:   
                    print("\nData has been loaded!\n")
                    loadcsv = pd.read_csv(filename)
                    cols = ['StudentID', 'Name']

                    for c in loadcsv.columns:
                        if c not in cols:
                            print("The uploaded file is not valid")
                    break
            else:
                    print("\nFile has not been found.")
```